# How to engage in the conceptualization process to measure a psychological construct such as femininity?

Tags: social-psychology, measurement, methodology

I am in class for Research Methods and I am having troubles with a conceptualizations process. The question is to describe the conceptualization process you would employ to measure femininity. How exactly do you do that?

Comment: Welcome to Cognitive Sciences Se! Homework questions are accepted, but some personal effort, or at least some background info on the topic is necessary. The help center contains heaps of info on this site.

Answer (score 3):

Conceptualization in a research methods context basically means generating a precise definition. You and I might have different ideas of what it means to be feminine, which would make it difficult to measure. In order to conduct research that measures femininity, a precise definition is needed so that everyone has a common understanding of what exactly it is that is being measured. You might start this process by identifying different aspects of femininity and generating a list. Then you could try to summarize your list with a few sentences that describes your conceptualization or definition of femininity.